# Has TabBarIOS an Icon-Only Style?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently playing with the TabBarIOS-Component. It works perfectly but what I'm missing is a Icon-Only Style like TweetBot. Is there a way to tell TabBarIOS that I don't need/want the title?

Comment: Have you tried leaving the title prop empty ?

Comment: Yes. It just leaves the space empty.

Answer (score 2):

You must explicitly set the title to an empty string:

```
<TabBarItem title="" />
```

Comment: Awesome. Works. Made my day but very unintuitive :-)

Comment: Ah, we should fix this.